# change entitymanager datasource in same session

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, entitymanager

in my session i need to call 2 diffrent procedures which are on db1 and db2. it works fine when i call them separetely but it fails when i call them in same session. it fetches first data correctly but it fails on second call since it looks for the second procedure on db1 although entitiymanager's datasource changed correctly.

what am i missing?

here is code snippet

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DB1Dao {

    @PersistenceContext()
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Model1 getData(String param1) {
    .....
    }
}

@Repository
@Transactional
public class DB2Dao {

    @PersistenceContext()
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Model2 getData(String param2) {
    .....
    }
}


@Autowired 
private DB1Dao dao1;

@Autowired 
private DB2Dao dao2;

@RequestMapping(value = "/inquiry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> inquiryService(@RequestBody InquiryRequest inquiryRequest){   
   ....
   Model1 model1 = dao1.getData(param2);   // success

  ....
  Model2 model 2 = dao2.getData(param2);  // fails since it looks for second procedure on db1
}
```

Comment: You cannot switch the datasource as it is tied to the `EntityManager` (or actually the active connection). But if you are calling a procedure why bother with JPA and not simply use JDBC? Another thing to take into account, is that an `EntityManager` might be opened very early due to `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`. You might want to disable this by setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false`. This might lead to some issues as you now loose lazy loading in the frontend.

Comment: it is a legacy project so i can not make big changes. is there any solution/workaround fits this structure or it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any persistence-related configuration info, but I'd guess you should differentiate your repositories by properly naming them:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "db1PersitenceUnitName")
        private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: what is it for unitName? it causes an error: 

...required a bean named 'db1PersitenceUnitName' that could not be found.                
 The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'db1PersitenceUnitName' in your configuration.

Comment: btw i am creating datasources on the application startup dynamiclly and changing datasources by extending AbstractRoutingDataSource class

Comment: From your persistence.xml: `<persistence>
   <persistence-unit name="db1PersitenceUnitName">
      <provider>org.hibernate...`

Comment: I never tried that because for me container managed was always enough. So please look at that routing code you have written (or copy it here).